# Separating dataset of images into different folders according to labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a label.csv file with 3 classes and my dataset is a whole file which is not separated I want to separate my dataset into 3 different folders, each folder should be each class, Kindly help me with the code I am stuck

```
# Create an empty dictionary to store the separate classes
classes = {}

# Iterate over each row in the dataframe and add it to the appropriate class based on its label
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    label = row[]
    if label not in classes:
        classes[label] = pd.DataFrame()
    classes[label] = classes[label].append(row)

# Print out the separate classes
for label, data in classes.items():
    print(f"Class {label}:")
    print(data)
```

My .csv files have 2 columns: the first column has the image name and 2nd column has the class label representing class 1 labelled as 1 class 2 labelled as 2 class 3 labelled as 3. Kindly do help me.

Comment: Where the original images are stored? In the same folder of `label.csv`?

Comment: images are in a different folder not in label.csv

Comment: please produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - it will help us understand the structure of the input table in the .csv

Comment: @hlin03 what i need is using the csv file i need to seggregate the images into 3 classes. please do help. My csv file has 2 columns first colum are the image names and 2nd are labels for 3 different classes

Comment: @PranshuJena, did you try my code?

Comment: sorry I am still quite confused. Can you please confirm if your current DataFrame looks something like this ```label_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "image": ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"],
        "class": [1, 2, 3, 1],
    }
)```? If yes, do you just want a Python dictionary outputted with the class as key, and a filtered DataFrame of all rows with that class as the dictionary's value?

Comment: What I need is only where the images are stored if it's not in the same place of your csv file. I updated my answer related to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import os
import shutil

# create class directories
for label in label_df['class'].unique().astype(str):
    if not os.path.exists(label):
        os.mkdir(label)

# set the destination target
label_df['path'] = label_df['class'].astype(str) + os.path.sep + label_df['image']

# copy or move files
for _, row in label_df.iterrows():
    # shutil.copy(row['image'], row['path'])
    shutil.move(row['image'], row['path'])
```

Input dataframe:

```
data = {"image": ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"],
        "class": [1, 2, 3, 1],     }
label_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```